# Which statistical method do I need for my research (combining correlation and independent two-samples t-test?)

Tags: correlation, t-test, predictor, two-sample

I need some guidance with my model, because I believe I need both correlation as well as an independent two samples t-test for my research.. is that even a thing?

[image]

My model claims that firm performance is dependent on information security performance, while information security performance is a construct consisting of IT governance quality and IT capabilities. So that should be testable with a Pearson's correlation.

But that's just one part of my analysis, because I don't just want to describe a relationship, I also want to test how the relationship between the variables (correlation) changes across independent groups. Is that possible or common in research?

I have thought about first doing the correlation for both samples to get the correlation coefficients for my variables and then in a second step I would test the difference between the two groups with a independent samples t-test...

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are several ways you could go about this, but what method is best depends on what exactly the research question is you want to answer. For example, you could estimate the edges of a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), and see how they differ between your two samples. Or you could do a [mediation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)) where the interaction between resources and capabilities is supposed to affect firm performance, but is mediated by information security performance.

Comment: (continued) If you edit your question to focus less on your proposed solution (combining a $t$-test with correlation), and more on the problem, it will be easier for answerers to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Hey Frans thanks for your advice and the kind words! I am a business undergrad student and the directed acrylic graph is maybe a bit beyond my statistical capabilities, but mediation analysis seems useful :-)   I have modified my research model now with IT capabilities as a mediator. See: https://imgur.com/a/N8KBXKD

Comment: @FransRodenburg Regarding your second tip: The main objective of my research is to determine the impact of "information security best-practice certification" on firm performance. "Information security performance" is mediating the relationship. That's also why I need to look at two distinct groups: firms that are certified to follow IS best-practices and firm who don't.